# WikiData : using 'of' property in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to find a path in WikiData from animal entities to the Animal entity ([Q729](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q729)). To do so, for some entites, the only way appears to be this (example from [jellyfish](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q30178)):[image]

Using a SPARQL query, I would need in this example to go from the jellyfish entity (Q30178) to the Medusozoa entity (Q6596143). To do so, I have to use the properties instance of (P31), of ([P642](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P642)) and the class 'organisms known by a particular common name' ([Q55983715](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q55983715)). I haven't been able to figure out the right combination.

Here are a few combinations I've tried in an ASK query :

```
wd:Q208342 wdt:P31 wd:Q25510.              # false
wd:Q208342 wdt:P31 wdt:Q55983715;
           wdt:P642 wd:Q25510.             # false
wd:Q208342 wdt:P31 wd:Q55983715.           # true
wd:Q208342 wdt:P31 [ wdt:P642 wd:Q25510 ]. # false
```

I can't seem to find any relevant Documentation regarding the usage of 'of' and 'common name'. Could you please help me connecting the two entities ?
Here is the [WikiData SPARQL query launcher](https://query.wikidata.org/).

Thank you for your time ! :)

Comment: the "of" is a statement qualifier in the Wikidata data model. You have to use a SPARQL query like `select * {
  wd:Q30178 p:P31 ?stmt .
  ?stmt ps:P31 ?o .
  ?stmt pq:P642 ?of
  }`

Comment: or if you just want the "of" value and this being required, a more compact query: `select * {
  wd:Q30178 p:P31/pq:P642 ?of
}`